# I can't seem to make my Parse.com Query work inside my DialogFragment

Tags: c#, android, parsing, xamarin, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to query from my Parse database after clicking a button in my Dialog Fragment but i get an "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" error. I keep seem to be able to find the source of the problem as it doesn't return a line of code with the error in it.

```
    void XLogIn_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     var query = ParseObject.GetQuery ("Votes")
            .WhereEqualTo ("Name", txtUser)
            .WhereEqualTo ("Password", txtPass)
            .WhereEqualTo("True", true);
        int count = query.CountAsync ().Result;
        if (count > 0) {
            Toast.MakeText (this, "Log In Complete", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
            dialogueFragment logIn = new dialogueFragment ();
            logIn.Show (transaction, "dialog fragment");
        } 

        else {
            Toast.MakeText (this, "Invalid data", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
        }
        }
```

Comment: post the stacktrace please. Parse returns an error exception as well. Do try to parse it if its not null. These 2 are the most common errors faced.

Comment: Comment out everything but the query to isolate the problem.  Also, you are using await inside a method that is not marked async.

Comment: Just fixed that and still have the same error. It seems to have a problem in the Async area that causes it to crash.